# Not able to return the new number after deleting the old one

Tags: java, arrays

I am using the following method to delete an element from an array. The array holds a set of class instances, each holding a name and number. So deleting for example position [3] from an array will delete the name and number at that position [3] and shuffle the positions in the array. I am able to delete the element as expected but having ArrayOutOfBounds error when I try to return the new number at the position [3]. (3 is just an example).

The first if statement is to handle arrayoutofbounds in case the element is the last one. In this case, even though the return statement is the same as the one giving problem, it works and returns correctly. Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
public String remove(String name) {
        //find() is a helper method that returns an int
        if (find(name) == Directory.length-1){
            Directory[find(name)] = null;
            return Directory[find(name)].getNumber();
        }
        else if (find(name) >= 0){
            //Directory is the array holding the class instances.
            for (int i = find(name); i < Directory.length-1; i++){
                    Directory[i] = Directory[i+1];
            }
            //this return is causing the error. 
            return Directory[find(name)].getNumber();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

As mentioned, the exception is ArrayOutOfBounds. 
For example the array contains ["Alan" "123"] in index 0 and ["Bobby" "456"] in index 1. When I delete the content in index zero, ["Alan" "123"] must be deleted and ["Bobby" "456"] must move down to that spot. The numbers 456 must be returned when the following return statement is called.

```
return theDirectory[find(name)].getNumber();
```

Comment: Please expand on the example. Post declarations, expected results, actual results. Include the definition of find and the exception.

Comment: `10 >= 0` is always guaranteed to be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better to only call `find()` once. Also, this way you can save the index to use later.

```
public String remove(String name) {
    int indx = find(name);
    if(indx < 0)
        return null;
    String num = Directory[indx].getNumber();
    if (indx == Directory.length-1){
        Directory[indx] = null;
        return Directory[indx].getNumber();
    }
    else{
        //Directory is the array holding the class instances.
        for (int i = indx; i < Directory.length-1; i++){
                Directory[i] = Directory[i+1];
        }
        //this return is causing the error. 
        return Directory[indx].getNumber();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: @keshk Sorry, I fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you. It works but weirdly returning ArrayOutOfBounds if indx is below 0.

Comment: The rest is working fine when I delete the last element or middle element as long as the number is positive.

Comment: Hmm, it shouldn't be. It should be returning `null` if `indx` is below 0;

Comment: Corrected it. My fault. I edited and placed String num = Directory[indx].getNumber(); on top of the if statement checking for -ve value.

Comment: Yes, that would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing this:

```
return Directory[find(name)].getNumber();
```

to return the index after you've removed the element from the array.  Because you've removed the name, the find() is not returning the same index any more.

What you want to do is set an int variable to the result of find(name) and use that variable instead of the find() method from then on.

Comment: I believe you mean the same as the codes as imtheman. It is not working. same arrayoutofbounds error.